# generalize a function in Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word, digits

I need to run "LTRrun" command to all digits through documents, I recorded macro while I apply this command manually some times then I run this macro multi times till end of document I work on.

Can anyone help me in editing below macro to run it one time to apply for all digits through file? I attached 2 screens for sample of text before & after running this macro.

```
Sub EN_digits()
'
' EN_digits Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
    Application.Browser.Next
    WordBasic.LtrRun
End Sub
```

I'm not coder or programmer, but I think there's a way to decrease this long macro to be applied to all document one time.
[Before running Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFdn9.jpg)
[After running Macro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBJqJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Something more like the following *may* do what you are asking for:

```
Sub EN_digits_2()
'
' EN_digits Macro
'
'
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "[0-9]"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchKashida = False
        .MatchDiacritics = False
        .MatchAlefHamza = False
        .MatchControl = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    While Selection.Find.Execute()
      Selection.LtrRun
    Wend
End Sub
```

NB, for many find/replace operations people would probably try to work with a .Range object rather than the Selection object, but LtrRun and RtlRun are not available for the Range object.

If you have any digits in text areas inside graphics objects, they may need to be treated differently.

But I wonder whether you might just need to change a Word setting to *see* the result you want - e.g. (with the English Language Interface, if you go to Word's File Menu, Options, Advanced, then look for the Show Document Content section, what do you see next to "Numeral" ? If I set that to "Context" I see the digits in the Arabic script. If I set it to "Arabic", which is the default setting here, I see the "Latin" digits (always a bit confusing unfortunately), depending on how the text has been entered.